# Get all file names starting with a prefix from Resource folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can we get all file names starting with a prefix from resource folder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 2023

Get all files ...

```
let ff = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "png", subdirectory: nil)!
```

Only pngs (say) ...

```
let ff = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "png", subdirectory: nil)!
          .compactMap{ $0.lastPathComponent }
```

Those that start with "jane"

```
let ff = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "png", subdirectory: nil)!
         .compactMap{ $0.lastPathComponent }
         .filter{ $0.starts(with: "jane")}

for f in ff {  print("filename .. \(f)") }
```

Answer (score 22):

You can achieve that adapting the following code:

```
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:
                  [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] error:nil];
NSArray *pngs = [files filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH[cd] '.png'"]];
NSLog(@"%@", pngs);
```

Running this code you will see the list of PNG's on your bundle. Change the predicate to match with the prefix you want:

```
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:
                  [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] error:nil];
NSArray *filesWithSelectedPrefix = [files filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                                    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH[cd] 'prefix'"]];
NSLog(@"%@", filesWithSelectedPrefix);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated for Swift 4.0:**

In my case, I was looking for files that began with `fileName-1.png` where there might be other files with the `fileName` prefix.

1) I thought about using regex, but splitting the string was faster and easier, so I went that route to get the prefix.

```
let myKnownFileNameString = "fileName-1.png"
let filePrefix = myKnownFileNameString.split(separator: "-").first
```

2) Create an empty array to store images you find:

```
var imageArray: [UIImage] = []
```

3) Then, get the URLs from the bundle, `filter` them and `map` the URLs to `UIImage` instances:

```
if let filePrefix = filePrefix, let fileURLs = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "png", subdirectory: nil) {
    imageArray = fileURLs.filter{ $0.lastPathComponent.range(of: "^\(filePrefix)", options: [.regularExpression, .caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil }
                         .map{ UIImage(contentsOfFile: $0.path)! }
}
```

From there,  you've got an array of images that you can do stuff with (animate them in a `UIImageView`, etc.)

Comment: There are more suitable and *swiftier* ways, for example you get all URLs with given extension with `Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "png", subdirectory: nil)` and instead of `NSPredicate` use `.filter{ $0.range(of: "^\(filePrefix)", options: [.regularExpression, .caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil }`