# Getting the txt file names starting with a particular word

Tags: objective-c, xcode, textfield

with reference to this question
  [Get all file names starting with a prefix from Resource folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244351/get-all-file-names-starting-with-a-prefix-from-resource-folder)
here it says the word 'prefix'. But in my app i need all the file names starting from the word given in a textfield into a table. How can i implement that? i tried with "%@" and then gave the textfield content. But its not working. But instead if i give something like "h" it shows all file names starting with 'h'. Please help with a reply.

```
-(IBAction)Do_Search:(id)sender
{    
    files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:
             [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] error:nil];
    search_results_array = [files filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                            [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH[cd] 'h'"]];
    NSLog(@"%@", search_results_array);
    int search_res_count=[search_results_array count];
    NSLog(@"Array has %d results...",search_res_count);
    [search_results_array retain];
    [Result_table reloadData];
    //till this part it works fine. I got all file names starting with 'h' in table. now what i need is i should get all file names starting with the word given in the search bok

    NSString *Search_string=Search_song.text;
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:Search_string ofType:@"txt"];  
    if (filePath) {  
        NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
        if (myText) {  
            song_lyrics.text= myText;  
            //what i did here is if i give a complete file name in the search field (textfield). i am getting the complete file contents inside a text view
        }  
    }  
}
```

I know the code is not in proper order now. i was trying with this top-down and bottom-up approaches..

Comment: Can you give the code where you're trying to implement this?

Comment: given the code. sorry for the late reply i was trying to load the data into a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was so simple.... instead of 'h' i removed the ' ' from there and gave %@ that is

```
search_results_array = [files filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH[cd] %@",Search_string]];
```

and there solved my issue... Thanks everyone :)

Comment: that can be done only after 20 hours... i will do that... please wait dear :)

Comment: twenty? Could've sworn it was a lot less than that....well, sorry for rushing you

Comment: they says i can accept my answer as a correct one only after 20 Hours... i am waiting for that.. now 20 minutes more :)

Answer (score 0):

Pl. change the line

```
search_results_array = [files filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH[cd] 'h'"]];
```

as follows

```
search_results_array = [files filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH[cd] '%@'",searchBoxText]];
```

Comment: the array is empty then here searchBoxText is Search_song for me.